# What does this symbol '<>' means in Laravel Query Builder?

Tags: sql, database, laravel

I know this is a really beginner question, but I don't know what the meaning of this. I'm reading the existing system code. I don't know what does this symbol means **<>** in Query Builder.

Here is the sample code:

```
$builder = DB::table('product');

if (isset($product->type)) {
        $builder->where('product.type', '<>', $product->type);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In [MySQL syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal), this is the same as `not equal` or `!=`.